# A book for questions on coordinate geometry

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems, book-recommendation

Can someone recommend me a book on coordinate geometry which focuses mainly on question solving and consists of ample amount of tough
 hybrid problems on 2 or more conics, topics like common tangents, etc

Answer (score 0):

You can go with Advance Problems in Co-Ordinate Geometry by Vikas Gupta , it has ample of good questions